# How to transform results (rows to columns) in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have data in the format below.

```
let T = datatable(OperationName:string, Result:string)
[
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "failure",
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "success",
   "Method1" , "failure",
   "Method2" , "success",
   "Method2" , "failure",
   "Method2" , "failure",
];
T | summarize  Total = count() by OperationName, Result
```

Which gives following:

| OperationName | Result | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Method1 | success | 4 |
| Method1 | failure | 2 |
| Method2 | success | 1 |
| Method2 | failure | 2 |

How to write a KQL which generates results like:

| OperationName | success | failure | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Method1 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| Method2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Basically, rows carrying result types (success/failure) move to columns, and respective count goes into each column. Also, total column is added at the end which is sum of success + failure.

Answer (score 2):

[pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin

```
T 
| evaluate pivot(Result)
| extend total = success + failure
```

or

```
T 
| evaluate pivot(Result, count(), OperationName) : (OperationName:string, success:long, failure:long)
| extend total = success + failure
```

or even simple *summarize* with *countif()*

```
T
| summarize success = countif(Result == "success")
           ,failure = countif(Result == "failure")
           ,total   = count()
            by OperationName
```